# show $f\mid A=f\circ{i_A}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

My question is

if $f:X\rightarrow{Y}$ and $A\subseteq{X}$, show that $f\mid A=f\circ{i_A}$.

So here's my attempt.

By definition of the inclusion map, $f|A$ is the function on A such that $(f\mid A)(a)=f(a), \forall{a}\in{A}$.  Also, by definition of the identity map on A into X, $i_X\mid A=i_A$.  Putting both together we get
$$f\mid A=(f\mid A)(a)=(f\mid A)(i_A)=f\circ{i_A}$$
This to me is short and sweet, but I'm trying to ensure my proofs are perfect and my logic flows correctly.  Also that my notation is correct, since this is the most abstract class I've had thus far.  No need to upvote or whatever, I just want to see if this is the way and if not, where I've missed (and hints if I'm wrong...)

Comment: Your notation is certainly in trouble. What exactly is the meaning of $f|_A = (f|_A)(a)$ supposed to be? The two things on each side of the $=$ are not the same thing -- they're not even the same _kind_ of thing.

Comment: I second Henning. Besides, composing a function with _identity_ does not change how that function works. I think the intention of this problem lies elsewhere, in particular, do you know what are the rules for composition operator $\circ$ with regard to domains and codomains (both of operands and the result)?

Comment: this is how it was defined in my book....it says "Explicitly, $f|A$ is the function on A such that $(f|A)(a)=f(a)$ for $a$ in $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to be a bit more explicit about what you are doing.  First, $f \restriction A$ is a new function such that $dom (f \restriction A) = A$ and $cod (f \restriction A) = cod (f)$ (the codomain) and with the property that $f \restriction A (x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in A$.

Also, $i_A$ is a function with domain $A$ and codomain $X$ such that $i_A(x) = x$ (necessarily all these $x \in A$).

Now, $f \circ i_A$ (notice this composition works!) is a function with domain $A$ (the domain of $i_A$) and codomain $Y$ (the codomain of $f$).  Moreover, $f \circ i_A (x) = f(x)$ and again necessarily since the domain is $A$ all these $x \in A$.

Hence, $f \circ i_A (x)$ and  $f \restriction A (x)$ have the same domain and codomain and moreover, $f \circ i_A (x) = f \restriction A (x)$ for all $x \in A$ (their domain) and so these functions are equal.

Comment: i think I see what you are doing...considering composition of functions we need to pay extra close attention to the domains and codomains of the function...my equality statement is way off then and I need to consider how the composition of both $f$ and $i_A$ look in regards to its domain and codomain.

Comment: Yes, you had the right idea ("morally" I think it was correct but missing some parts). Just make sure to be more explicit about what is actually happening.

Comment: I suspect that the original exercise actually assumes that $i_A$ is $A\to A$ but that $f\circ g$ is defined as long as the codomain of $g$ is contained in the domain of $f$.

Comment: That's what I had thought at first, but if you look at the definition he is using $i_A$ "is the identity map on $A$ into $X$" and he sets it as $i_A = i_X \restriction A$.  But good point nevertheless.